# scrapy crawler showing error while crawling

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl couponation website coupon's but when i am 
     trying to run crawler its showing error.Please help.
     Thanks.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
class CuponationSpider(scrapy.spider):
   name = "cupo"
   allowed_domains = ["cuponation.in"]
   start_urls = ["https://www.cuponation.in/firstcry-coupon#voucher"]
   def parse(self, response):
      all_items = []
      divs_action = response.xpath('//div[@class="action"]')
      for div_action in divs_action:
         item = VoucherItem()
         span0 = div_action.xpath('./span[@data-voucher-id]')[0]
         item['voucher_id'] = span0.xpath('./@data-voucher-
                  id').extract()[0]
         item['code'] = span0.xpath('./span[@class="code-
               field"]/text()').extract()[0]
         all_items.append(item)





   >**Output** ERROR  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
raise URLError(err)URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2017-07-25 16:36:59 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving 
 up
```

Comment: The answer to your problem is in the warning.  Don't use scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector use  scrapy.Selector

Comment: @Neil  still problem not solved i tried that also.

Comment: So what is the warning now? And what is the error?

Comment: @Neil---File "/home/abhinav/Coupons/Voucher/Voucher/spiders/Couponation.py", line 13, in parse
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
NameError: global name 'scrapy' is not defined

Comment: @Neil---File "/home/abhinav/Coupons/Voucher/Voucher/spiders/Couponation.py", line 13, in parse
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
NameError: global name 'scrapy' is not defined

Comment: @Neil i assigned global variable too.

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working.  the code above doesn't contain the word ``scrapy``.

Comment: @Neil  ----At place of (hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)) this.. I put scrapy.Selector

Comment: I suggest you look at the scrapy documentation.  It sounds like you are missing the scrapy import.

Comment: Is the above code your full scrapy file? And pls check your indentations

Comment: @KaushikNP ----------indentations is ok .crawler is executing fine.I think error is in xpath.

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**: ... tell me the error where i am doing

1. Remove all your `import` Lines, use **only** one:

   ```
   import scrapy
   ```
2. Your Class Inheritance should be:

   ```
   class CuponationSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   ```
3. You have changed `name` and `starturl`, use:

   ```
   name = "cuponation"
   allowed_domains = ['cuponation.in']
   start_urls = ['https://www.cuponation.in/firstcry-coupon']
   ```
4. You use **Python 2.7**
   Sorry couldn't run `Scrapy` with **2.7**. This could be the difference.
   The **ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving**, tells you didn't receive any Data from the given URL. Maybe you are Blacklisted.

---

> **Comment**:   URL is cuponation.in/firstcry-coupon#voucher

This is the **same** Page no need to reload it.
All could be simplified to the following:

```
all_items = []

def parse(self, response):
    # Get all DIV with class="action"
    divs_action = response.xpath('//div[@class="action"]')

    for div_action in divs_action:
        item = VoucherItem()

        # Get SPAN from DIV with Attribute data-voucher-id
        span0 = div_action.xpath('./span[@data-voucher-id]')[0]

        # Copy Attribute voucher_id
        item['voucher_id'] = span0.xpath('./@data-voucher-id').extract()[0]

        # Find SPAN class="code-field" inside span0 and copy Text
        item['code'] = span0.xpath('./span[@class="code-field"]/text()').extract()[0]

        all_items.append(item)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> #CouponSpider.start_requests:https://www.cuponation.in/firstcry-coupon
> #CouponSpider.parse()
> #CouponSpider.divs_action:List[13] of <Element div at 0xf6b1c20c>
> {'voucher_id': '868600', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '31793', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '832408', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '819903', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '808774', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '32274', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '32102', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '844247', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '843513', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '848151', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '845248', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '869101', 'code': '*******'}
> {'voucher_id': '869328', 'code': '*******'}
> ```

Comment: @stovfl-----I uploaded my all code but still facing problem.

Comment: i have done all the changes but still i am noot able to get the results.

Comment: @stovfi  -- i have changed only xpath and that url is taking proper coupon id which one i want to fetch..

Comment: @abhi09sep: My Answer Code is working! Tested with Python 3.4

Comment: @stovfl-- i have updated code as per you but still not getting output..

Comment: @stovfl--can you share output what you got?

Comment: --but you are not getting particular code of coupon in result.

Comment: @abhi09sep: These are the Results of the static Site Data. `Scrapy` can't scrap Data injected from `javascript` you are seeing if you use a Browser.

Comment: so any another possible way to crawl coupon codes? Any suggestions